# Modeling time series in python with statsmodels and getting unexpected results and strange charts

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels, timeserieschart

I am doing some time series modeling (or trying to). I'm doing just a simple auto AR but am having issues with the output (so probably the input as well). The data is pretty straight forward. There are times, days since start and the values I want to model and forecast.

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.tsa.ar_model import AutoReg, ar_select_order

train7 = p7.iloc[:len(p7)-1728]
test7 = p7.iloc[len(p7)-1728:]

mod = AutoReg(train7['Gv'], 5, old_names=False)
res = mod.fit()
print(res.summary())

pred = res.predict(start=len(train7), end=(len(p7)-1), dynamic=False)

from matplotlib import pyplot
pyplot.plot(pred)
pyplot.plot(test7['Gv'], color='red')
```

This produces a crazy chart seen below.

The prediction x axis values are way outside the range of what they should be. i.e. pred shows ranges outside the x axis range and they are not in proper order, which seems reflected in the chart below.

The p7 data looks like :

```
rec1; Gv:100; time: 23:50:39; days from start: 0
rec2; Gv:150; time: 23:55:39; days from start: 0
rec3; Gv:190; time: 00:00:39; days from start: 1
```

I'm at a loss. Clearly I've skipped or missed something important. First time modeling TS in python.

[image: This is what I get]

Comment: I think the index for p7 is not correct.  What does `pf7.head(10)` look like?

Comment: p7.head(10) shows that you are correct. I forgot to reset the index.